# Is that possible to use double TabHost in one Activity without TabActivity

Tags: android

I have home Activity that has a xml customed HostTab, when I define a Fragment with anoter HostTab (with different id) inside the home Activity's HostTab content, the home Activity' HostWidget cant be shown correctly. I believe the issue is that the id of HostWidget (android:id="@android:id/tabs") is conflict.

Is that possible to use double TabHost in one Activity without TabActivity?

Any answer will be appreciated.